# why bin folder occupying more space in my android project?

Tags: android, apk

When I try to copy my project from eclipse to usb it shows 30mb, I was shocked because I haven't use that much of resources in my project. So checked the entire project, bin folder occupying 17mb of size and it contains duplicates of all of my resources in project...and also it contains apk file. can I use that apk file directly to test instead of exporting the apk file?

Comment: Just clean the project and build again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the build process, your Android projects are compiled and packaged into an .apk file, the container for your application binary.  Eclipse outputs an .apk file automatically to the bin folder of the project, so it occupying more memory. You can find detail explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> why bin folder occupying more space in my android project?

while you are building and Cleaning the project bin folder generated by eclipse automatically. you will get more Details [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421699/what-is-a-bin-folder-for-in-android)

> can I use that apk file directly to test instead of exporting the apk
>   file?

**Yes,** you can use that APK file to test your Application by installing in your device.

Comment: Great link it has sorted out all my doubts regarding bin folder...thank you @Bhavesh