# AndroidManifest.xml duplication

Tags: android, eclipse

I use to make modifications in the Androidmanifest.xml file in the root folder of my project. But I discovered that there is an AndroidManifest.xml file in the \bin folder too. Is it automatically created and updated by Eclipse? Or did I copy it there by mistake?

Sometimes this file in the \bin folder is not aligned to the main AndroidManifest.xml, and in this case I see crashes and strange behaviours in my app.

Comment: it is automatically created file. Even if you delete this it get recreate it next time when you build your app

Comment: in bin all files will be automatically generated, you should neither remove it or edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version in `bin` is put there by the build process and you should not modify it yourself. Only modify the manifest in your project root.

When the files differ, there was a build problem of some sort. If cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help, have a look at the console tab for specific build problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I make a full project cleaning in Eclipse?

Comment: `Project` -> `Clean` if my memory serves me.

Answer (score 0):

It is system generated after successfully compiling your project. You need not to change anything under /bin folder. Clean your project if there is any mismatch, it will update itself.

[Reffered from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421699/what-is-a-bin-folder-for-in-android)

The compiler uses the bin folder as a sort of staging area to prepare your files to be finally packaged into your APK. This includes compiling your Java code into class files and also putting your resources (including images) into a certain structure to be zipped into the APK. It's required to have a separate copy because the Android SDK does some preprocessing on these images before packaging.